GET request to `getOne` controller. Postman returns no data from MongoDB and causes endless request loop
sample data and postman req image I am sending "get" request on Postman. Using Express. Unfortunately, there is no luck and I can't find the mistake. Here is my factory.js :
exports.getOne = (Model, popOptions) =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('GET ONE');
    let query = Model.findById(req.params.id);
    if (popOptions) query = query.populate(popOptions);
    const doc = await query;
    if (!doc) {
      return next(
        new AppError('No documents fond with that id', 404)
      );
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        data: doc,
      },
    });
  });

controller :
exports.getTourById = factory.getOne(Tour, { path: 'reviews' });

I tried to change controller and at the end no luck ana here is sample data in my DB.

What framework is this? How is catchAsync used? There are many missing details crucial to answering this question.

Using express framework. and here is catchAsync: ```module.exports = catchAsync = (fn) => {
return (req, res, next) => {
fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
};
};


can you edit your question and add a tag for express then?

@devoz It would be idea if you could edit your question, adding the proper tags. Postman seems to be irrelevant here. Also, please add a minimal reproducible code piece. So that we can see the whole code.
